# Pivottable in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Dataframe like this:

```
Col1 Col2
A    Foo1
A    Foo3
B    Foo1
B    Foo3
B    Foo4
C    Foo1
D    Foo3
D    Foo4
```

And I need an output like this:

```
       Foo1     Foo3      Foo4
A    1             1            0
B    1             1            1
C    1             0            0
D    0             1            1
```

What is the simplest way in pandas to reach this, without using foreach loops in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest is [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['Col1'], df['Col2'])
```

Another solution is [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Col1','Col2']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print (df1)
Col2  Foo1  Foo3  Foo4
Col1                  
A        1     1     0
B        1     1     1
C        1     0     0
D        0     1     1
```